# circular image horizontal scrollview in android so that when i reach last image, first will come and when i reach first image, last will come

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview, circular-list

Hello i am using the horizontal image scrolling with the reference of [Slide show Demo](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo) .

Now i want to make it circular so that when my 43rd image comes the scroll will not be stopped it should come with the first image.

i have added the images like this.

```
public void addImagesToView() {
    for (int j = 0; j < Utility.image_array.length; j++) {
        final Button imageButton = new Button(this);
        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(Utility.image_array[j]);
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        imageButton.setTag(i);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (isFaceDown) {
                    /*
                     * if (clickTimer != null) { clickTimer.cancel();
                     * clickTimer = null; } clickedButton = (Button) arg0;
                     * stopAutoScrolling();
                     * clickedButton.startAnimation(scaleFaceUpAnimation());
                     * clickedButton.setSelected(true); clickTimer = new
                     * Timer();
                     * 
                     * if (clickSchedule != null) { clickSchedule.cancel();
                     * clickSchedule = null; } clickSchedule = new
                     * TimerTask() { public void run() {
                     * startAutoScrolling(); } };
                     * clickTimer.schedule(clickSchedule, 1500);
                     */
                }
            }
        });

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                256, 256);
        params.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 25);
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalOuterLayout.addView(imageButton);
    }
}
```

i just want to know that how we can make this 43 images circular smoothly So that when i scroll to right and reach to last image it should scroll RIGHT with the 1st image and so on. same as the left scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

This is InfiniteScrollView may help you or give you an idea for scrolling and circular scrolling 
https://github.com/satansly/InfiniteScrollView

I hope that help you.